# Cypress Click if item exist

Tags: cypress

I need a way to easily trigger a `click()` event only if an element exist on page.
the fact that the element (confirm modal dialog) itself exist is not an issue for my test, but this can stop next steps. so I want to click OK only if the dialog is shown.

I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
  cy.get('body').find("button[data-cy=sometag]").then(items => {
    if(items.length) {
       cy.get('button[data-cy=sometag]').click();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Is this the element `button[data-cy=sometag]` that will exist and not exist sometimes on the webpage ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test that the modal exists but don't want to fail the test if it doesn't, use a jQuery selector.

```js
const found = Cypress.$('button[data-cy=sometag]').length
```

Modals are likely to animate on opening, so you you will need to repeat the check a few times, which you can do in a function

```js
function clearModal(selector, timeout = 1000, attempts = 0)
  if (attempts > (timeout / 100)) {
    return;                                  // modal never opened
  }
  if (!Cypress.$(selector).length)  {        // not there yet, try again
    cy.wait(100)
    clearModal(selector, timeout, ++attempts)
  else {
    Cypress.$(selector).click()             // modal is up, now close it
  }
}

clearModal('button[data-cy=sometag]')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the find like this `cy.get('body').find("button[data-cy=sometag]")` this will fail always whenever the element is not present. Instead you can use the find command inside the If condition and check its length.

```
cy.get('body').then($body => {
    if ($body.find("button[data-cy=sometag]").length > 0) {
        cy.get('button[data-cy=sometag]').click();
    } else {
        //Do something
    }
})
```

Instead of `body`, you can also use the parent element of the element in question, which you know for sure is visible and present on the page every time.